# How can I use system variable in mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I use system(operating system) variables like JAVA_HOME In my own mysql stored procedure.

Comment: u mean somehow directly in mysql ? i am not shure if thats possible at all

Comment: Any other way if direct approach is not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you may need to use an external library such as UDF Repository for MySQL to do this. A reference to the library can be found [here](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/). There should be a sys_get() function call that may serve the purpose.

Comment: I am using it as SET path = sys_get(JAVA_HOME) , but response is null every time although JAVA_HOME is set.

Comment: Can you please help me in logging where I am lacking.